# Display results of success over attempts in X/Y format

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am tracking the number of successes out of the total number of attempts. 
So, for example, Column A would be the number of successes. Column B would be the number of fails. I would like Column C to show the number of Success over the total number of attempts.

Example:
A:4 B:3 C:4/7

He had 4 successes out of 7 attempts. 
Is this possible?

Also accounting for zero entries.

Example:
A:0 B:7 C:0/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=A1/SUM(A1; B1)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B1:B); A1:A/(A1:A+B1:B); ))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B1:B); IF(A1:A=""; 0; A1:A)&"/"&(A1:A+B1:B); ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is perfect thank you very much!

Comment: @Allister https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers